# Adding large file to Docker build gives EOF exception

Tags: docker, dockerfile

To restore our production db locally, I'm adding a Postgres dump to a Docker build file. Until recently this was a smooth process. But as the db steadily grows (now +80G), it seems as though I've hit an unknown treshold. The build crashes at a simple `ADD dmp.sql.gz /tmp/dmp.sql.gz` line in the Dockerfile (so *before* it actually unzips or executes the contents of the file)

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  87.42GB
Step 1/6 : FROM ecr.url/postgres96
 ---> 36f64c15a938
...
Step 5/6 : ADD dmp.sql.gz /tmp/dmp.sql.gz
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF
```

logs of the Docker deamon don't give me much of a clue:

```
Aug 15 10:02:55 raf-P775DM3-G dockerd[2498]: time="2018-08-15T10:02:55.902896948+02:00" level=error msg="Can't add file /var/lib/docker/overlay2/84787e6108e9df6739cee9905989e2aab8cc72298cbffa107facda39158b633d/diff/tmp/dmp.sql.gz to tar: io: read/write on closed pipe"
Aug 15 10:02:55 raf-P775DM3-G dockerd[2498]: time="2018-08-15T10:02:55.904099449+02:00" level=error msg="Can't close tar writer: io: read/write on closed pipe"
```

I followed up on the actual copying of the file to the overlay fs, expecting to see it crash somewhere in the process, but it actually crashes *after* the whole file is transferred:

```
root@raf-P775DM3-G:/home/raf# ls /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e1d241ba14524cff6a7ef3dff8222d4f1ffbc4de05f60cd15d6afbdb2bb9f754/diff/tmp/ -lrta
total 85150928
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 87194526754 Aug 14 00:01 dmp.sql.gz // -> this is the whole file
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root        4096 Aug 14 17:30 ..
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root        4096 Aug 14 17:30 .
```

When this dmp file was in the 70GB range, restoring it in this fashion was a time consuming but smooth process,on different OSes and Docker versions.

Does anyone can help figuring out the gist of the problem?

Currently experiencing this issue on `Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825`

Ps: I read about a tar header limit of 8GB which causes a EOF exception (https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37581) but again, we were restoring 70GB+ dumps without issue.

Comment: Can you verify the gz file is valid by manually uncompressing it outside of docker? E.g. `tar -tvzf dmp.sql.gz`

Comment: Did any of the files within the dump cross over the 8GB threshold?

Comment: In the past I've had operational trouble (like `docker save` and `docker pull` not really being reliable) with images only in the ~10 GB range.  Since what you're describing is a single large data file, it seems like it would make sense to distribute it via another path (say, rsync or S3) and just bring it in at runtime via a Docker host bind-mount option.

Comment: @BMitch it's not a .tar.gz file but uncompressing with gunzip works. The archive contains just 1 sql file (176GB)

Comment: @DavidMaze Sure, there are workarounds. But an image with the data already there is really nice to work with. For one thing, populating data on a (empty) running container requires extra scripts to be maintained. Now it's all in the dockerfile. Again, this used to work... But we'll manage

Comment: Did you also upgrade your docker install when this happened?

Comment: @BMitch yes, I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to 18.09. They changed the tar backend which should fix this issue. As for why the 70GB file worked, I suspect it has something to do with compression in the layers since you cannot trigger this issue with an 8GB file of zeros. See https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/37771.