# Docker build crashes when I download large file (40GB) on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, openstreetmap, nominatim

I'm building a Docker image on Ubuntu 16.04.
It consists of curl command that downloads a file, it passes for small files, but when I download a large one (40GB), it crashes with a following error:

`Step 35/68 : RUN curl -L ${PBF_URL} --create-dirs -o /srv/nominatim/src/data.osm.pbf
 ---> Running in 9fb68ab31988
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 39.9G  100 39.9G    0     0  8855k      0  1:18:55  1:18:55 --:--:--  9.8M
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF`

Here is a link to a Docker file that I'm running:
 https://github.com/merlinnot/nominatim-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile

I use a strong server to build it, 50 GB of RAM, 10 cores. I tried tinkering with memory parameters like `--memory-swap -1 --memory 32g`, but it didn't really help.

I would like to point out that I'm not downloading `tar` file and I have no intentions of uncompressing it.

The file itself is fine, I tried downloading it separately, works great.

Any ideas on how could I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure this is specific to Docker and you're able to download it without problem out of Docker ? It not, maybe take a look at this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428233/download-big-file-over-bad-connection

Comment: The error `Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF` does not seem to come from the `curl` command.

Comment: Try downloading the file yourself and then test it with tar (`tar -tf <filename>`). This will tell you whether or not the file is OK. If it is fine, you could add it as part of your Dockerfile. Please note that Docker untars tar archives inside the container when using the `ADD` command.

Comment: Here is another post where someone has issues with a large tar file: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51855702/4459346

Answer (score 2):

The tar command is used to package the new layer of the image, and in 18.06, there appears to be an 8GB limit in that step. I'd recommend:

- Following the issue on github to be notified when it's been resolved: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37581
- Moving your data out of the image. Your image should be the application binaries and libraries, but not the data itself. The data should be mounted into the running container as a volume.